# How to implement a Restricted Boltzmann Machine manually?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, programming

I am learning about Restricted Boltzmann Machines and I'm so excited by the ability it gives us for unsupervised learning. The problem is that I do not know how to implement it using one of the programming languages I know without using libraries. I want to implement it manually, which means that I want to use native functionalities of a language as much as possible.

The programming languages I know are Java, C, PHP (my preferred language), JavaScript, R and Python. I am not familiar with TensorFlow or Scikit-Learn or similar stuff.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ML From Scratch has an [implementation](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/ML-From-Scratch/blob/master/mlfromscratch/unsupervised_learning/restricted_boltzmann_machine.py) in Python

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. Sorry if my question is stupid and a bit off-topic, but how can I prepare data and feed it to this? Should I format my data as a vector and pass it to the third argument of the function fit() after initializing the class as an object?

Comment: Not entirely certain about the exact interface, but I believe it follows the sklearn interface. Meaning that you instantiate an RBM object, then pass the data inside the fit method (as the X argument). The X argument should probably be a 2-dimensional array/iterable (n_samples x n_features)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should ask it separately on a different question, but how can I find data like that? I'm very new to this field, so I'm afraid of asking questions because I feel my questions may be immature. Should I find a CSV file and then turn it into a 2-dimensional array or data scientists use another way to format the input data?

Comment: You probably find some use cases on Kaggle.com. When it comes to data, you use whatever you can find, if it's a csv, a text file, a json document, or even on a database, it doesn't matter. Then it's up to you to read and parse the data into whatever format you'd like!